# useState and function .map

Tags: react-hooks

```
const Monsters = function () {
const [allMonsters, setAllMonsters] = useState([]);
const [specificMonster, setSpecificMonster] = useState([]);
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

const openModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
}

useEffect(() => {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://mhw-db.com/monsters',
    })
        .then((res) => {
            setAllMonsters(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, [])

const getSpecificMonster = (id) => {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://mhw-db.com/monsters/${id}`,
    })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(`Je clique sur la modale avec l'id : ${id}`);
            console.log(res.data);
            setSpecificMonster(res.data);
            openModal();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}
return (
    <div className='monstersContent'>
        <h1 className='monsterContent-title'>Listes des Monstres <span>Monster Hunter</span></h1>
        {!modalVisible && (
            <div className='cardsMonster'>
                {allMonsters.map((items) => (
                    <div className="cardMonster" key={items.id}>
                        <p className='cardMonster-name--title'>{items.name}</p>
                        <p>Type du monstre : <span className="cardMonster-espece"></p>
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => { getSpecificMonster(items.id) }}>Voir plus d'informations</button>
                    </div>
                )
                )}
            </div>
        )}
        {modalVisible && (
            <>
                {specificMonster.map((items)=>(
                     <p className='cardMonster-name--title'>{items.name}</p>
                ))}
                <div className="cardMonster"></div>
                <button onClick={openModal}>Retour</button>
            </>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

hello, i want to use .map but i have a error which i dont understand

> Uncaught TypeError: specificMonster.map is not a function

How can i do for rendering the informations of specific monster ? When i want to use

> specificMonster.map

I always got an error

Thanks for help

Comment: The API call that you are getting data from to populate specificMonster does not return an array, it returns an object.  So there is no map function available.

Comment: so i need to use forEach to read an object ? (im new in dev)

Comment: You can just read the object directly.  Please see below answer.

Answer (score 0):

`specificMonster` is being set to an object, not an array.  So, you can just access the properties directly:

```
<p className='cardMonster-name--title'>{specificMonster.name}</p>
```

You should also change the useState initialization value to an object:

```
const [specificMonster, setSpecificMonster] = useState({});
```